# Failed to invoke signalR

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, signalr

I am trying to send notification to My client(Angular) from .net core server(c#) using signalR. to notify client when the event is fired. But i am getting an error. 
Error: Error: Failed to invoke 'Send' due to an error on the server

Appcomponent.ts

```js
ngOnInit() {
 this._hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
.configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
.withUrl("http://localhost:5000/message/Send", this.transportType)
.build();
}
form(){
this._hubConnection.on("Send", (data) => {
  const received = `message: ${data}`;
  console.log(received);
  that.disabled = false;
});
  this._hubConnection.start()
.then(() =>
this._hubConnection.invoke('Send', "hey")
.catch(function (err) {
 console.error(err.toString());
})
)
.then(() =>
console.log('connected'))
.then(() => this._hubConnection.stop())
.then(() => console.log('Disconnected'))
.catch(e => console.error(e.message));
}
```

SignalR hub

```cs
public class DataHub : Hub
{
    public async Task Send1(string message1, string Root)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("Send1", message1);
    }
}
```

Controller

```cs
public class DataController : Controller
{
    private IHubContext<DrawingHub> _hubContext;
    public DataController(IHubContext<DataHub> hubContext)
    {
        _hubContext = hubContext;
    }
    private void OnProvideData(DataAndHeader data)
    {
        // server side code
        _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("Send", data);
    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```cs
services.AddSignalR();

app.UseSignalR(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapHub<DrawingHub>("/message/Send");
            });
```

Error logging

> fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.DefaultHubDispatcher[8]
>         Failed to invoke hub method 'Send'.
>   System.IO.InvalidDataException: Invocation provides 1 argument(s) but target expects 0.
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocol.JsonHubProtocol.BindArguments(JArray args, IReadOnlyList`1 paramTypes)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocol.JsonHubProtocol.ParseMessage(Utf8BufferTextReader textReader, IInvocationBinder binder)

I want to invoke the signalr connection to notify client after the server side code is executed in the event. Can someone please guide me. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: your hub method is called `Send1` but you are calling `Send`

Comment: I want to invoke Send from OnProvideData Method.

Comment: that's the event you are listening for on the client. but on the client you are also trying to invoke "Send", which does not exist on the Hub. see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method name you call on the client must be the same as in your SignalR Hub (with the exception that lowercase methods are also allowed).

Since your Hub method is called `Send1` and your client calls `Send`, the method is not found. To fix the issue you can rename your Hub method to `Send` or change your client code to call `this._hubConnection.invoke('send1', "hey", "ho")`.

Here's what you do:

- `this._hubConnection.on("Send", ...` have the client listen for a server event called `Send`.
- `this._hubConnection.invoke('Send', "hey")` invoke a server method called `Send`. THIS DOES NOT EXIST! the server method is called `Send1`!
- `public async Task Send1( string message1, string Root)` declare a method called `Send1`. nowhere in your client you are you trying to invoke `Send1`, only `Send` (without `1`).
- `await Clients.All.SendAsync("Send1", message1);` if `Send1` would be invoked, you'd try to publish a `Send1` message to all clients. no client is listening for `Send1` though, only for `Send`.

Now look at your error message: `Failed to invoke hub method 'Send'.` it's looking for a hub method `Send` but it does not exist, because you called it `Send1` instead.

Quick Fix: Simply rename all occurrences of `Send1` to `Send`. Because that's what you are trying to invoke on your client. In Addition, you also have to call it using 2 arguments, not one like currently, since the hub method has 2 parameters.

Comment: I want to invoke Send from OnProvideData Method in controller not in Send1 in Hub.

Comment: i added moer detail. you want to invoke send on the hub from your client. that's what the error message and your code says (`this._hubConnection.invoke('Send', "hey")`)

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your patience and time. I understood it. My end goal is to implement a logic on my client when the server event is listened by client. I mean when the **this._hubconnection.on** is successfull i want to enable a button in my client using **this.disabled = false**. can you please suggest me how can i integrate it.

Comment: your original question is about failing to invoke signalR. my answer should fix this. now to your follow up: that should be fixed by this as well, because that's what you are already doing in your code.

Comment: Hi, the original question works fine with your answer. But the follow up is not working. I want to implement _hubconnection.on_ function from my controller not from my Hub.

Comment: you should accept the answer then, follow ups normally should be asked in a new question so more people can see it and are able to help. i suspect that you still got a typo somewhere when calling the client method. pushing messages to the client from the controller is done via `IHubContext`, just like you already do.

Answer (score 1):

In your `startup.cs`, you should register signalR service and map your hub in the http request pipe, if you have not done that already.

#### Step 1

`startup.cs --> ConfigureServices()` needs to register the signalR service, e.g:

```cs
services.AddSignalR();
```

`startup.cs --> Configure()` should contain your mappings, e.g:

```cs
app.UseSignalR(routes =>
{
   routes.MapHub<YourHubClass>("/hub/test1");
   routes.MapHub<YourHubClass2>("/hub/test2");
});
```

More options can be added, if needed. But I belive the defaults are good enough for now.

#### Step 2

Your hub class can simply just inherit from : Hub for a test to work. But to show some consol output, you can override virtual Hub functions like this:

```cs
public class YourHubClass: Hub
{
    public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Context.ConnectionId);
        await base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }

    public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Context.ConnectionId);            
        await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(ex);
    }
}
```

#### Step 3

Depending on when/where in you back-end code you want to notify all clients (or specific clients) that are listening to you hub, you can simply emit the data you want to transfer by doing something like this.

```cs
var test1data = GetTest1Data();
await _hub.Clients.All.SendAsync("test1", test1data);

var test2data = GetTest1Data();
await _hub.Clients.All.SendAsync("test2", test2data);
```

Where `_hub` is dependency injected in this scope. Just to clarify that:

```cs
private readonly IHubContext<YourHubClass> _hub;

public YourScopedConstructor(IHubContext<YourHubClass> hub) 
{
    _hub = hub ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(hub));
}
```

#### Step 4

Now you can connect and listen to your hub. E.g:

```ts
public yourSubscribableSubject: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
private _baseUrl: string = "your base url";
private _frontendHubConnection: HubConnection;

this._frontendHubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl(`${this._baseUrl}/hub/test1`) // or hub/test2
        .configureLogging(LogLevel.Information)
        .build();

this._frontendHubConnection
        .start()
        .then(() => console.log('SignalR - init'))
        .catch(err => console.log('Error while starting connection: ' + err));

 this._frontendHubConnection.on('test1', (data: any) => {
        console.log(data);
        this.yourSubscribableSubject.next(data);
    });
```

And for any other component to get the data, just subscribe to `yourSubscribableSubject`. Hopefully it helps.

Also, if you want to trigger the data to be sent from server to clients from the API endpoint, just move the scoped code i suggested from step 3.

```cs
public async Task<ActionResult> YourApiRoute()
{
    try
    {
        var test1data = GetTest1Data();
        await _hub.Clients.All.SendAsync("test1", test1data);
        return Ok();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
    }
 }
```

Comment: I am trying to implement it in _private void OnProvideData(DataAndHeader dh) method_ is it correct or should i make any changes. because i am not able to recieve any data from my controller.

Comment: Well, it does not look 100% accurate at the moment. How does your startup.cs look from step 1 of my example?

Comment: In your "SignalRhub" section, the Task Send1() is not doing anything it seems like. You simply want to push a message from the server to clients, right? Or do you also want to send data from a client to trigger Send1() method in your hub? So your client(s) should subscribe to `http://localhost:5000/message/Send` - just like you have done. So now you only need to trigger the emit event from the server code. It does not matter if the function is private/public, you just need to trigger it.

Comment: what you said is correct. I only want to push a message from server to client. I am not sure whether the emit event is triggered on server side or not.  I want only __hubconnection.on_ to function properly so that i can log the data and enable a Button.

Comment: Do you get any errors when you connect your cleint to the server? If not, you are probably connected. If you use a browser like chrome, you can inspect the network traffic in the developer tools. Most likley a websocket connection is stablished. I suggest you create API route in your controller to trigger the event from the server. But you also need to trigger the API route with a request, GET request are the simplest to do. Look at the bottom of step 4 and replace it with your own code, eg: ` _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("Send", data);`

Comment: btw in your Controller, the `IHubContext<DataHub>` class does not match.

Comment: i tried to provide similar code .it is a mistake while mentioning here. Thanks